# Merging query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following subquery:

```
Acc    Tel            Prod1    Prod2
1000 | 281-xxx-4809 |   No  |   Yes
1000 | 281-xxx-4809 |   Yes |   No
```

How do I select those two columns by the `Acc` column into only one like this:

```
Acc    Tel            Prod1    Prod2
1000 | 281-xxx-4809 |   Yes |   Yes
```

Using SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't this work?

```
select Acc, Tel, max(Prod1), max(Prod2)
group by Acc, Tel
```

It's based on alphabetical order, but that works fine for you.

Comment: not really a nice way thinking of readability... but really nice though :)